# Count the occurences of a list of words in files

Tags: shell

I have a list of words like this, separated by line:

```
Range
Balance
Total
CombinList
CombinRow
GridKey
KeDanJia
AddRowNum
TopList
Keysearch
Keysearchtaobao
IsearchData
IsearchDataSep
...
```

And I have some files under a directory:

```
$ tree
.
|-- a.txt
|-- b.txt
|-- c.txt
|-- d
|   |-- a.txt
|   |-- b.txt
|   |-- c.txt
|   |-- d.txt
|   |-- e.txt
|   |-- f.txt
|   `-- g.txt
```

How can I count the occurrences of words in those files? Output should be like:

```
Range: 0
Balance: 32
Total: 100
CombinList:4
CombinRow: 3
GridKey: 1
KeDanJia: 43
AddRowNum: 5
TopList: 34
Keysearch: 0
Keysearchtaobao: 1
IsearchData: 12
IsearchDataSep: 123
...
```

Comment: Do you have excel?

Comment: No, I only have a remote shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your list of words is in a file called `/path/to/words.txt` and your tree is located at `/tree` for the purposes of this example, try:

```
find /tree -name '*.txt' -execdir sed 's/ /\
/g' {} + | grep -Fw -f /path/to/words.txt | sort | uniq -c | \
awk '{print $2 ": " $1}'
```

Comment: After reading John's answer I realized that both his and my original answers only count line frequencies so if a word appears multiple times in a line the count would be incorrect.  My updated answer has the following changes: use `sed` to split input files one word per line and add `-w` option to `grep` so for example `Range` in `words.txt` will not match `Ranger`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
  FILENAME == ARGV[1] {word[$0]=0; next}
  {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      if ($i in word) word[$i]++
    }
  }
  END {for (w in word) print w ": " word[w]}
' word.file $(find . -type f -print)
```